# How to insert data typed on a TextBox from modal into database

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a JavaScript modal that opens on a button click and has two text boxes and a button. The button has the task to insert the data that has been typed into the text boxes to a database. But, I don't know why, when I click the button it just refreshes my page and the data is not inserted into the database. I also wrapped two alerts in a try/catch block, thus the one appears if the operation is successful and the other one if not, but for some reason after clicking the button none of them appears (the alert after an unsuccessful operation needs to pop up). I've searched the whole Internet but I don't know why for my certain case I can't find a thing (most of the solutions were for PHP).

**How to make the button that is on the modal functional and to collect the data from the text boxes and insert to the database?**

**Here is the HTML code of the modal:**

```html
<i class="fas fa-info-circle" id="info"></i>
<div class="popup" id="popup">
  <div class="modal-container" id="modal_container">
    <div class="popup_left">
      <div class="popup-img_container">
        <img
          src="img/database_system.jpg"
          alt="Database System"
          class="popup_img"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="popup_right">
      <div class="right_content">
        <h1>Can't reach me online?</h1>
        <p>
          Please type your e-mail and provide a brief explanation of your
          intention/purpose of contacting.
        </p>
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <asp:TextBox
            ID="email_textbox"
            CssClass="popup_form"
            placeholder="Please enter your e-mail"
            runat="server"
            Required="required"
          ></asp:TextBox>
          <asp:RegularExpressionValidator
            ID="validator1"
            runat="server"
            ErrorMessage="Invalid character, your e-mail address must contain @"
            ControlToValidate="email_textbox"
            ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"
          ></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
          <asp:TextBox
            ID="email_message"
            CssClass="popup_form"
            placeholder="Message"
            runat="server"
            Required="required"
          ></asp:TextBox>
          <asp:Button
            ID="Message_button"
            runat="server"
            Text="Send"
            type="button"
            OnClick="Message_button_Click"
          />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button id="close" type="button">
      <div class="popup_close">
        <svg>
          <use xlink:href="img/sprite.svg#icon-cross"></use>
        </svg>
      </div>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Here is the C# code:**

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=;Initial Catalog=Contacts;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=;Password=");
    protected void Message_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ContactsTable VALUES ('"+email_textbox.Text+"','"+email_message.Text+"')";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        try
        {
            script += successMessage;
            script += "')};";
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "SuccessMessage", script, true);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            script += dbFailMessage;
            script += "')};";
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "dbFailMessage", script, true);
        }
        email_textbox.Text = "";
        email_message.Text = "";
    }
```

**Here is the JavaScript code:**

```
const info = document.getElementById('info');
const popup = document.getElementById('popup');
const close = document.getElementById('close');

info.addEventListener('click', () => {
   popup.classList.add('show');
});

close.addEventListener('click', () => {
   popup.classList.remove('show');
});
```

**Grateful for any help.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, there are some issues here.

first up, it not quite clear what JavaScirpt libaries you are using to pop up that dialog - there are a LOT of them. It kind of looks like bootstrap, but there must be more the.

But, lets keep this nice and simple. I'll use jQuery.UI (since 99% of sites already have jQuery, adding the jQuery.UI library seems reaonsable).

So, how will this work?

Ok, we will pop the dialog. If the user hits cancel, then we just dismmiss (close) the dialog. if user hits add, then our plain jane button (in that pop dialog) will then do a post back and run code behind like any other simple button.

Because that plain jane button does a post back, then of couse the dialog will collapse and be dismissed for us.

So, say we have this markup:

```
        <asp:Button ID="cmdAddHotel" runat="server" Text="Add a Hotel" OnClientClick="popaddhotel();return false"/>

        <div id="AddHotelPop" style="text-align:right;display:none">

            <p>Hotel Name:<asp:TextBox ID="txtHotel" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></p>
            <p>First Name:<asp:TextBox ID="txtFirst" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></p>
            <p>Last Name:<asp:TextBox ID="txtLast" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></p>
            <p>City:<asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></p>
            <p>Province:<asp:TextBox ID="txtProvince" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></p>
            <p>Is Active:<asp:CheckBox ID="chkActive" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox></p>

            <p>
                <asp:Button ID="cmdAddOk" runat="server" Text="Ok-add" OnClick="cmdAddOk_Click" />
                <asp:Button ID="cmdCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" Style="margin-left:25px"
                    OnClientClick="MyClose();return false"/>
            </p>
        </div>

        <script>

            function popaddhotel() {
                var mydiv = $("#AddHotelPop")
                mydiv.dialog({
                    modal: true, appendTo: "form",
                    title: "Add Hotel", closeText: "",
                    width: "400px"
                });

            }

            function MyClose() {
                popdiv = $('#AddHotelPop')
                popdiv.dialog('close')
            }

        </script>
```

ok, we now get this:

[image]

And our simple button code behind to add to the database is this:

```
    protected void cmdAddOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblHotels WHERE ID = 0",
            new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST3)))
        {
            cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
            DataTable rst = new DataTable();
            rst.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            SqlDataAdapter dUpdate = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL);
            SqlCommandBuilder sUpdate = new SqlCommandBuilder(dUpdate);
            DataRow OneRow = rst.NewRow();

            OneRow["FirstName"] = txtFirst.Text;
            OneRow["LastName"] = txtLast.Text;
            OneRow["HotelName"] = txtHotel.Text;
            OneRow["City"] = txtCity.Text;
            OneRow["Province"] = txtProvince.Text;
            OneRow["Active"] = chkActive.Checked;
            rst.Rows.Add(OneRow);
            dUpdate.Update(rst);

        }
    }
}
```

so above is quite simple - clean, and we can follow the button clicks etc.

The above of course used jquery.ui for this (so you have to add that).

Edit: the question was asked which js libraries am I using.

Well, out of the box, all asp.net sites based on default templates have jQuery, so only jQuery.UI need be added.

But, to keep this all in one - for this post?

I included jquery.
jqquery.UI, and the nice theme for jQuery.UI.

You will note that we don't even need bootstrap libraries for this.

Sure, this works:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am not using any libraries it is just Vanilla JavaScript, do you need the CSS code also?

Comment: No, but my simple jquery.UI example stands quite well on its own, and the resuilt is quite a nice dialog pop. and as you can see, how the code to send that ok button click to the database is also quite nice and easy to work with.  If your popup is working now, then adopting the code I posted for the button click (using a asp.net button) should thus work fine for you. So you really don't need jQuery.UI as I used. If your dialog is popping up just fine? Then that button click code behind should add the one new row to the given database rather just fine.

Comment: Which generation of jquery.UI u've used? I tried to link it with a CDN and with a downloaded jquery.ui folder but after clicking the "Add a Hotel" button nothing happens.. If it is not a problem please provide that part of the code also, thank you.

Comment: you only need the above mark up. I did a edit - see VERY end of my answer - I include and show the jquery, jquery.UI and even the jquery.UI theme for this to work. I don't use CDN, but for this post - above works fine. Note that you don't even need boot strap for this to work. As noted, I don't use the bootstrap dialogs since they are very messy and very difficult to work with. You can with above just paste in the markup for testing (don't even need the code behind stub to add - but just leave that blank, so you can cut + paste and run the example in a blank new test page.

Comment: I should note that it is often better to use the buttons of the jQuery.UI dialog in place of your own buttons like I did, but since one of the buttons was a asp.net button with code behind stub, then using buttons in the div as opposed to the built in jQuery.UI dialog was a bit less effort.

Comment: In my case without the linking it does not seem to work, but when I added them, it works PERFECT. Thank you very much I really appreciate your help.

Comment: In order to understand where I was wrong, could you please explain to me what do you think that was causing the problem? Some JS code or the ASP button that had the task to insert the text into the data base?

Comment: Hard to tell. I don't use any other dialog system then jQuery.UI. I find it just works well. Even default older asp.net projects have jQuery. So adding jquery.UI and the theme is quite small. jquery.ui can load a div, but in fact you can popup even a whole seperate aspx page, and that even works well. So I high recommend. As for your issue? It is possible that your  pop up was not putting back what you type into the controls, and thus on post back they were all blank? Don't really know. I just went with jquery.ui for all my pop dialogs etc - and it just works, so that's what i use.

Comment: Yes, they were blank and nothing else happened nor my alerts for successful or unsuccessful operations were shown.. very strange. I had this same issue couple months ago, but I can't figure out why with a popup that loads after 2 seconds when the page runs It worked perfectly with this same code, but on a modal that you must press a button in order to be opened did not worked.. May be some problem in the CSS because the modal is hidden and has no pointer-events until the moment is clicked then they switch to auto.. I really don't know. Anyway, thank you again and have a nice day.